# How to clear cache on each php page when it loads in the browser?

Tags: php, caching

I want to clear browser cache in each page when it loads in the browser. I used clearcache() php function but it did not work for me. please help.

Thanks.

Comment: why? what actual problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: The clearstatcache() function clears the file status cache.
PHP caches data for some functions for better performance. If a file is to be checked several times in a script, you probably want to avoid caching to get correct results. To do this, use the clearstatcache() function.

Answer (score 5):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
//header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

for clearing browser cache

Comment: For clarity, this does **not** clear the browser cache. This tells the browser not to cache the page in the first place. And the Content-Type header probably shouldn't be there (at least not statically like that)

Answer (score 4):

Using php you can put this code to your head section of website:

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the expires header to a past date. It will only be relevant for "clearing the cache" of a particular page..... if the browser wants to. Theres little serverside code can force on the client when it comes to this sort of stuff. It can basically only make recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this meta tag

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot clear the whole browser cache using php :(